# How many teams of 5 players can be chosen from a group of 10 players? How many teams will include the best player and exclude the worst player?

Tags: combinatorics

This was a question from my textbook. This is how I approached it.

For the first part, you can do c(10,5) so you choose 5 of the 10 to be on a team.

For the second part, you have 10 ways to choose the "best player" and you multiply it by c(10,4) to pick the other 4 players. However, I am not sure how you can exclude the "worst player". Although this sounds subjective, I believe the question is saying that the "best" and "worst" players are distinct, whereas the other players aren't.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be making an incorrect assumption about how the problem should be interpreted.  The way I read the problem there is a very clear single person who is considered "the best player" and no choice is needing to be made as to who it is.

A rephrasing of the question:

How many $5$-element subsets are there of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,9,10\}$ such that $1$ is included and $10$ is not included in the subset.

*Hint:*

Compare this to the problem of asking how many $4$-element subsets there are of the set $\{2,3,4,\dots,9\}$ there are.  Do you see what this has to do with your original problem?

Comment: If I understood that correctly, would it be c(9,1) x c(8,4) where c(9,1) is choosing the best player, and c(8,4) is choosing the rest of the team? Also, we already excluded the worst player by only choosing from 9 players.

Comment: @Zaku again, in my interpretation of the problem, we know before ever starting who the best player is.  We do not "*choose the best player.*"  Consider my rephrasing of the problem again.  $1$ is the analogue for the "best player" and $10$ is the analogue for the "worst player."  If it makes you feel better, imagine we had the players tested for aptitude ahead of time and then rather than bothering to remember their names we only bother to remember their rankings.

Comment: @Zaku the answer of $\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{4}$ might be an acceptable answer for a related problem of "*How many ways can I make a team of five people where one of them is designated as the captain where the worst player is not included on the team.*"  In this related problem, we *do* have a choice of who the captain will be and it can change from one outcome to another, but in the original problem again the best player is always the same and never changes.

Comment: So there's only 1 way to have the best, and 1 way to have the worst. So we would not have to consider it when choosing the 4-member team, so we could do this with just c(8,4)?

Comment: Yes, but remembering that we are not choosing a four member team we are choosing a five member team.  The point is to recognize that to choose a five member team which includes the best this is equivalent to choosing the remaining four team members to be included with the best.